# Error Creating Table java.sql.SQLException: JDBC LLR, table verify failed for table 'QQE4D.WL_LLR_I0_LTAPP107', failed to create table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an issue with weblogic and jdbc configuration. We are using weblogic 12c and jdbc to connect to oracle.

I am getting an error while creating a table with name WL_LLR_ADMINSERVER.

**Below is the error**

> Failing reason: javax.transaction.SystemException: Failed to call registerLoggingResourceTransactions() weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException: weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException:     java.sql.SQLException: JDBC LLR, table verify failed for table 'QQE4D.WL_LLR_I0_LTAPP107', failed to create table javax.transaction.SystemException: Failed to call    registerLoggingResourceTransactions() weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException: weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException:   java.sql.SQLException: JDBC LLR, table verify failed for table 'QQE4D.WL_LLR_I0_LTAPP107', failed to create table.

The query being fired to create the table is

> JDBC loggging last resource (LLR) connection pool KernelDataSource did not find its table and is creating a new one using the following SQL:
>    **CREATE TABLE QQE4D.WL_LLR_I0_LTAPP107 (XIDSTR VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, POOLNAMESTR VARCHAR(64), RECORDSTR VARCHAR(1000))>**

The code congigured for the datasource in xml file is

```
 <jdbc-system-resource>
<name>KernelDataSource</name>
<target>cluster</target>
<descriptor-file-name>jdbc/KernelDataSource-int-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
```

The datasource xml contains the connection url, driver name, username and the encrypted password details.

I have seen some errors like below but for my case i am not able to create the table itself so i could find the exact solution for my issue.

> weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC LLR, table verify failed for table 'DEV_SOAINFRA.WL_LLR_ADMINSERVER', row 'JDBC LLR Domain//Server' record had unexpected value 'osb_domain//AdminServer' expected 'osb_cluster_domain//AdminServer' ONLY the original domain and server that creates an LLR table may access it.

Even i don't see these datasources linked to this server in weblogic console as well under monitoring tab. I guess we can see once this issue gets resolved.

I have seen that the atable name should not exceed 18 characters and my table WL_LLR_SERVERNAME is WL_LLR_I0_LTAPP107 which is exactly 18 characters and this is also not an issue.

Can someone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Does your QQE4D user have the `create table` privilege, and quota assigned on their default tablespace? Have you checked other log files to see if an actual ORA- error is reported separately, saying what the underlying issue might be?

Comment: Hi Alex,  there is no ORA error i could find in the logs and i am not sure why exactly this is getting failed. The id QQE4D is having all the required permissions to create the table

Comment: If you can create it manually as that user then WebLogic will check it exists, and not try to create it again. If you can't create it manually, that will give you an ORA error to investigate.

Comment: Hi Alex, i will try to check in that way and will see if that helps me.